# UPDATE em duas tabelas

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

Eu gostaria de fazer um `update` usando um `Inner Join`.

Eu tentei isto:

```
UPDATE m SET m.rua = 'Rua Major Gote', b.desc_bairro = 'Centro', 
       m.id_tipo = '', m.numero = '652', m.CEP = '38700001', m.cidade = 'Patos de Minas' 
FROM tb_marker as m
INNER JOIN tb_tipo as tp 
  ON tp.id_tipo = m.id_tipo 
INNER JOIN tb_bairro as b 
  ON b.id_bairro = m.id_bairro 
WHERE m.id_marker = 1
```

Mas recebi este erro:

> #1064 - Você tem um erro de sintaxe no seu SQL próximo a 'FROM tb_marker as m INNER JOIN tb_tipo as tp ON tp.id_tipo = m.id_tipo

É possível fazer um update deste tipo? Se sim, como?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sintaxe está errada.

A ordem das coisas deveria ser diferente, algo como:

```sql
Update `tabela`
Inner Join `OutraTabela`
  On CondicaoJoin

Set Campo = 'Valor'
Where Condicao
```

Aplicando ao seu código atual

```sql
UPDATE tb_marker m

INNER JOIN tb_tipo as tp 
  ON tp.id_tipo = m.id_tipo 
INNER JOIN tb_bairro as b 
  ON b.id_bairro = m.id_bairro 

SET m.rua = 'Rua Major Gote', 
    b.desc_bairro = 'Centro', 
    m.id_tipo = '', 
    m.numero = '652', 
    m.CEP = '38700001', 
    m.cidade = 'Patos de Minas' 

WHERE m.id_marker = 1
```

Comment: Tava preparando a resposta.. Mas pode olhar outro exemplo e uma explicação no https://stackoverflow.com/a/8057585/4551469

Comment: Deu certo aqui! Obrigado!!

Comment: Vou dar um olhar no link.